# Generating Calculated Fields by Time Period in Report Builder 3.0

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've spent weeks building a massive view, followed by a massive report in SSRS/Report Builder 3.0 that shows master inventory levels, purchasing levels, stock outages, etc. in fine form. The end result of this report is that I'll have every one of our stock items listed as rows, and collapse-ably grouped by vendor. As columns, I have time values, currently grouped by year and then by month (I'd like to add seasons/quarters here down the road, since we're a very seasonally oriented business, but that can wait right now).

Right now, the report shows the following columns for each month, per item (row): Quantity Shipped, Quantity Received in Stock, Stock Levels at the end of the Period, Avg Time Spent Out of Stock in the Period, and the Number of Outages within the period.

So, what I need now in order to finish up this beast is the estimated daily usage. To get this, I want to get the period length, by the column groupings, and subtract the sum(DaysOutofStock). The result would be Days in Stock, which I'd then divide by the totals shipped in the period.To boil this down, I just want to know that on days when the item is in stock, we're moving X on average.

So what I need is the period length, as a value to use in a function. Is there any way to get this automatically? Is it hidden somewhere in the function menu? Is there a function or expression I can use that will look at the month or grouping or whatever of the column and tell me that the month I'm in has X days?

My underlying data has massive gaps, especially earlier in the company's life, so there's no easy way to derive it from there (at least, that I can think of). Please help! I'm so close to finally finishing this project! Thanks!

If you need any more info or details, I'll be happy to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can do it in SQL code, the month in your report has the following days:

```
SELECT [Year], [Month], DateDiff(dd, CAST(CAST([Year] AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST([Month] AS VARCHAR) + '-01' AS DATETIME), DateAdd(mm, 1, CAST(CAST([Year] AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST([Month] AS VARCHAR) + '-01' AS DATETIME))) AS DaysDifference
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Ahh! Super clever. I'm going to splice it into my report query and make sure I can get it to factor correctly. I'm using Report Functions to pull Year and Month right now. I'm wondering if I can do this same logic within the functions of the report builder, or if I should do it all through the query instead. Is there a benefit, in performance or otherwise, to doing it either way? I suppose it'd be more portable within the query, which would help me move the whole thing from my development server to the main server.

Comment: It sounds from your question that this is a figure that you will require a lot in your calculations, in which case I'd put it into the view itself. The main benefit I look for is having the data in the form that is most re-usable rather than re-implimenting functionality everywhere. That way when you need to adjust it, for example to take into account quarters as well as months, then you only have to do it in one place.